# IK controlling library for Schunk 7-DOF manipulator

Tags: ros, kinematics, inverse

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,
since i have initialized my Schunk 7-DOF arm, i would like to ask , is there any inverse kinematics library to control this manipulator?
PS: Ubuntu 12.04 LTS/FUERTE

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/172106/ik-controlling-library-for-schunk-7-dof-manipulator/) by [Qt_Yeung](https://answers.ros.org/users/13976/qt_yeung/) on ROS Answers with karma: 90 on 2014-05-30

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gracecopplestone](https://answers.ros.org/users/26005/gracecopplestone/) on 2016-02-26**:
Hi there, I'm just starting to work with 2 Schunk 7-DOF arms. Which library did you end up using?

**Comment by [greenfield](https://answers.ros.org/users/26142/greenfield/) on 2016-03-09**:
Hi I am interested as well.

**Comment by [Qt_Yeung](https://answers.ros.org/users/13976/qt_yeung/) on 2016-04-22**:
I used MoveIt! library,  you can try it http://moveit.ros.org.

**Comment by [Qt_Yeung](https://answers.ros.org/users/13976/qt_yeung/) on 2016-04-22**:
I used MoveIt! library,  you can try it [link text](http://moveit.ros.org/).

**Comment by [PatFGarrett](https://answers.ros.org/users/34824/patfgarrett/) on 2018-07-30**:
Hello, I am working with a similar arm. I am having trouble with connecting MoveIt! to the COB software. Did you have issues there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See the http://wiki.ros.org/care-o-bot stack

---

Originally posted by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) with karma: 2573 on 2014-05-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Qt_Yeung](https://answers.ros.org/users/13976/qt_yeung/) on 2014-05-30**:
Do you mean the stack cob_manipulation? I also find ikfast from OpenRAVE and KDL solver on the internet. Can I use either of them to do inverse kinematics controlling? Sorry for this simple question, i'm a beginner.

**Comment by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) on 2014-05-31**:
I don't have experience with that stack. Download and test it to find it out :)